# Embedded Youtube Video not working on iPhone or iPad

Tags: youtube-api, html5-video

I have a youtube video embedded on my landing page (focus.brainbeat.com/adhd).  It works just fine on desktop and on Android phone but it does not play on iPhone or iPad. Below is the code that's being used...

```
<div class="Lightbox Lightbox--demo" id="demo">
    <div class="Lightbox-wrapper">
        <p class="Lightbox-close"><a href="#">Close</a></p>
    <iframe id="demo-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/058eNc41xVk?wmode=opaque&version=3&enablejsapi=1" height="450" width="800" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>

    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
```

Why isn't it working?

Thanks for your help!